# Colorbox loading too far down page

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I have a page which pops a colorbox up when clicking a hyperlink.
I moved the hyperlink to further down the page, and the colorbox popup also now loads further down the page.
I'm using the default CSS and the code I'm calling the colorbox with is:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        });
    </script>
```

I also have some other javascript that takes input from a box and then outputs the link itself. The appended code to this is:

```
jQuery('a.post_bid_btn_new').colorbox({ opacity:0.5  });
```

Now the link itself works, just too far down the page. Viewing the source of the colorbox popup, it has a CSS property of top: 1650px; obviously meaning it's displayed almost off-page.

Can anybody advise how to get around this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by setting top: when calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add positioning rules in css like:

```
.colorBoxClass{ 
               top: 300px;
 }
```

And give these rules to colorbox by '`className`' property when you call its method:

```
jQuery('a.post_bid_btn_new').colorbox({ opacity:0.5, className:'colorBoxClass' });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That doesn't seem to do anything though. The class doesn't seem to be being applied when viewing with Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

> Now the link itself works, just too far down the page. Viewing the source of the colorbox popup, it has a CSS property of top: 1650px; obviously meaning it's displayed almost off-page.

Have never had someone with this problem, and I've answered thousands of questions about colorbox.  Do you have a demonstration of the problem?  I don't think anyone is going to be able to give you a decent answer without being able to inspect it as it is just not something that would happen under normal circumstances.